# Capture data sent to printer

Tags: python, networking, printing, thermal-printer, network-printers

I have a POS application running on windows machine which prints data and does not allows to save the data. I try to print to pdf but does not seem possible. I would like to capture the data send to the printer maybe from the USB port and then later convert it to human readable text. I am pretty new to this, so a detailed answer with all steps will be much appreciated. Also to note its a thermal printer, just so if it makes difference!

Comment: Could you print to [a virtual printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software) that would allow you to save the file as a pdf?

Comment: Is it possible to record the communication contents with the printer connected by the serial port by using software such as a virtual serial port, a serial port redirector, or a serial port monitor? If you analyze the recorded data with another software, you will be able to extract the printed contents.

Comment: If you know the command specifications of the printer used by the application and the specifications are published, you can create software that analyzes based on the specifications. For example here. [receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools](https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/escpos-tools) I also have software in the process of being created. [kunif/EscPosUtils](https://github.com/kunif/EscPosUtils)

Comment: @KJ that sounds best to print to pdf, the thing is in the software we are able to select printers in software/app settings and there i see Microsoft print to pdf option, but when i select it and then come to main interface of the software from where it print receipts, and then click on print, no dialog is opening and nothing happens, which generally opens when we print to pdf. Also no dialog opens when i select thermal printer, but it prints. The thermal printer used is from STAR company!

Comment: @KJ yes when i print from other place it shows this conventional install printer "Microsoft Print to pdf" and works!

Comment: Thank you for the answers, the app is from schapfl pos - https://www.schapfl.de/kassensystem/ . In print settings of the software(which is different then normal print dialog), i see xps printer as well, but also after selecting that nothing happens when i click print in the software.

Comment: I will check the changing ports to file option, but than how to i convert PRN files to human readable text?